# How to know a gcc's c++ object's RTTI information from "this" pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, polymorphism, rtti

Under VC++, a polymorphic class, there's an extra pointer above the object's this pointer(pointing to vtable), pointing to its RTTI information.

I wish to know for GCC's compiled code, does an object store extra information associated with its RTTI information, and is there a way to visit it in c++ code, or can be visited by gdb through fixed offset/location?

Thanks.

Comment: [give typeid a look.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ object layout for polymorphism is implementation dependent. For example:

- [Article on the Visual C++ implementation of RTTI](http://blog.quarkslab.com/visual-c-rtti-inspection.html).
- [Article on the G++ implementation of RTTI](http://spockwangs.github.io/2011/01/31/cpp-object-model.html)

According to their author, both implementation use an RTTI pointer which is located just before the vtable.

Note that both differ from the original memory layout considered by Bjarne Stroustrup (see "*The Design and evolution of C++*") which had the RTTI pointer as first element of the vtable.   It's not fully clear to me why they diverged from this simpler idea.  Perhaps this was due to compatibility reasons, RTTI having been introduced only [in 1998](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/history).  For Visual C++ there could also have been some patent consideration: at that time, a [Microsoft's patent](http://www.google.ch/patents/US5297284) protected their own vtable layout).

All this is non-portable, so it's of interest only if you want to dissect your code or writing some debugging code.  If you intend writing portable software, better limit yourself to [`type_info`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/) with [`typeid()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).